# InvalidArgumentException: Package magento/product-enterprise-edition not found

Tags: upgrade, magento2.3.2, magento2.2.3

```
composer show magento/product-enterprise-edition 2.3.* --all | grep -m 1 versions
```

> [InvalidArgumentException]   Package
>   magento/product-enterprise-edition not found
>
> show [--all] [-i|--installed] [-p|--platform] [-a|--available]
>   [-s|--self] [-N|--name-only] [-P|--path] [-t|--tree] [-l|--latest]
>   [-o|--outdated] [--ignore IGNORE] [-m|--minor-only] [-D|--direct]
>   [--strict] [-f|--format FORMAT] [--] [] []

I'm sure I used the right key for enterprise, but it was wrong。Help!!!